# one to many relationship help in laravel 4

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, foreign-key-relationship

I am trying to create a relationship between Category and Product but somehow I couldn't use the category to connect into the product table and prints out the product names and instead I get the category's name

### in my database

```
Table Name: products
Columns: id, name, price, category_id, description
Table Name: categories
Columns: id, name, description
```

### in products table

```
id: 1
name: product1
price: 10
category_id: 1
description: p1
---------------
id: 2
name: product2
price: 10
category_id: 1
description: p2
```

### in categories table

```
id: 1
name: category1
description: c1
---------------
id: 2
name: category2
description: c2
```

### Product.php inside models folder

```
class Product extends Eloquent
{
    protected $product = 'products';
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Category');
    }
}
```

### Category.php inside models folder

```
class Category extends Eloquent
{
    protected $category = 'categories';
    public function product()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Product', 'category_id');
    }
}
```

### ProfileController.php in controller folder

```
class ProfileController extends BaseController
{
    public function user($username)
    {
        $user = User::where('username', '=', $username);

        if ($user->count())
        {
        $user = $user->first();
        $title = 'User Profile';
        $category = Category::find(1);
        $products = Category::find(1)->name;
        return View::make('profile.user', compact('user', 'title', 'category', 'products'));
    }

    return 'User Not Found. Please Create an Account';
}
```

}

### user.blade.php inside profile folder which is inside view folder

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('content')
    {{ Auth::user()->username }}
    <br>
    {{ Auth::user()->email }}
    <br>
    <h1>{{ 'Category name: '. $category->name }}</h1>
    <br>
    <h3>{{ 'Category Description: ', $category->description }}</h3>
    <br>
    {{ $products }}
@stop
```

at first where the `{{$products}}` I used a foreach loop

```
@foreach($products as $product)
    {{$product}}
@endforeach
```

but then I got this error

```
ErrorException
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: J:\wamp\www\test\app\views\profile\user.blade.php)
```

so I tried `var_dump($products)` and realized `$products` gives out `category1` which is the name of the category but what I want is printing the name of all the products which has category_id 1

Can someone give me a hand with this?  Did I mess something up with the relationship or I did something stupid with the codes?

Comment: Does your categories can contain multiple products and does your one product may goes in more than one category ?

Comment: This part doesn't make sense to me:

$category = Category::find(1);
$products = Category::find(1)->name;

Shouldn't it be $products = $category->product; ?
Please use plural on one to many relationships btw (products)

Comment: kevin> I thought I used plural where needed, did I miss something? Can you point it out please so I can change it.  Thanks ^_^

Comment: Your product relationship is based on a hasMany design.
$category->product doesn't make sense in a way that a category most likely has more than one product, using plural makes it easier to understand later on (so $category->products in your case)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your controller:

```
$category = Category::find(1);
$products = $category->product;
```

Then in your template you can use:

```
@foreach ($products as $product)
    {{ $product->name }}
@endforeach
```

Better yet you could use eager loading and forget about assigning products manually:

Controller:

```
$category = Category::with('product')->where('id', 1)->first();
```

Template:

```
@foreach ($category->product as $product)
    {{ $product->name }}
@endforeach
```

PS: Read more on eager loading here: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading
in order to prevent the dreaded N + 1 query problem!

Comment: thanks kevin, I am quite new with laravel and I was watching tutorial on youtube on relationships and this was used  `$post = Post::find(1);`  `$comments = Post::find(1)->comment;` I believe I misunderstood the video

Comment: if possible can you tell me what's the `comment` in `$comments = Post::find(1)->comment;` means? I thought `comment` is the column's name but seems like it's not

Comment: I figured I should stick with one method and get to know it better before trying others even though eager loading sure seems way easier :P

Comment: Laravel is easy to learn, a bit difficult to master but in my opinion completely worth digging into. Eager loading is a function that will, especially in large data driven applications, save your butt when it comes to performance and usability.

The ->comment you refer to as probably seen in your tutorial, is the same as your Category::find(1)->product..it fetches all records based on a given relationship (belongsTo, hasOne etc..)

Comment: thanks a lot but one last question so `Category::find(1)->product` the `product` here how did this `product` word come out? what I meant is...is it the model's name? or a word created anyhow I want it?

Comment: It's neither...it's the name of the method you use for declaring your relationship. For example you have a method called 'products' that has: return $this->hasMany('Product');. Category::find(1)->products means find all products using the 'products' method that belong to this model, based on the relationship you provided.

Comment: ah! ok that makes it clear and makes so much sense now!  thanks a lot...gonna change my notes I took when I was watching the video :P